# Error when trying to compile "Files has invalid value MustMatchAttribute"

Tags: .net

When copying a project over from another machine I got this error, a clean/rebuild didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix this you have to manually delete any bin and obj folders in your solution, then clean/rebuild.

Comment: You might also need to unload and reload the projects to get the dlls rebuilt

Comment: Thanks, you save my day.